# Finding the change in angular acceleration over time when unwinding a tape roll with a constant speed

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find an expression for the change in rotation speed over time as a tape roll is unwound at a constant speed. I started with the formula: $$w= \frac{v}{2\pi r}$$ where $w$ is rotations per seconds and $v$ is the tangential speed (in my case this is constant at 0.5 m/s). $r$ starts at 36.8 mm and ends at 12.7 mm (when tape is fully unwound).

The known parameters: 
Tape thickness: $k = 0.0625 mm$ 
Tangential Speed: $v = 0.5 m/s$ 
Initial radius: $r_{start} = 36.8 mm$ 
Final radius: $r_{final} = 12.7 mm$

I have tried the following but got stuck as I do not know how to solve the resulting equation:

$w(r)= \frac{v}{2\pi r}$
$r(t) = r_{start} - k \cdot w(t) \cdot t$
$w(t) = \frac{v}{2\pi \cdot r(t)}$

$$\frac{dw}{dt}=\frac{dw}{dr} \cdot \frac{dr}{dt}$$

$$\frac{dw}{dr} = \frac{v}{2\pi}\cdot \ln(r) + c $$

$$\frac{dr}{dt} = -k\cdot \left(\frac{dw}{dt} + w(t)\right)$$
$$\frac{dw}{dt} = -k\cdot \left(\frac{dw}{dt} + w(t)\right) \cdot \frac{dw}{dr}$$

This is as far as I got before I realized this is far beyond my ability and knowledge, I appreciate any help I get and deeply thank any whom takes on this endeavor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you took $\frac {dw}{dr}$ you integrated instead of differentiating.  It should be $\frac {dw}{dr}= \frac {-v}{2\pi r^2}$  To compute $r$ it is more useful to consider $r(L)$, where $L$ is the length of tape in millimeters on the roll.  When we increase $L$ by $2 \pi r(L)$ we increase $r$ by $0.0625$, so we have $\frac {dr}{dL} =\frac {0.0625}{2 \pi r}$ which we can solve to get $\pi r^2=0.0625L+c$.  At $L=0, r=12.7$, so $c=\frac {12.7}{\pi}$  and $r=\sqrt{\frac {0.0625}{\pi}L+\frac {12.7}{\pi}}$  Then $\frac {dr}{dt}=\frac {dr}{dL}\frac {dL}{dt}=\frac {dr}{dL}(500 mm/sec)$

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot, I am a bit ashamed of the integration/differentiation mix up. Cheers!